# How can I build PJSIP with bcg729 for Android?

Tags: android, pjsip, g729

I tried all the way I founded but not working.
First I download bcg729 project to build file libbcg729.a
I followed instruction here : https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/2029
But when I run `TARGET_ABI=armeabi-v7a ./configure-android --use-ndk-cflags --with-bcg729=/Users/bienpx224/Desktop/bcg729`
and then `checkbcg729 usability.... no`  -> wrong

Second I tried follow that to build pjsip project with a patch of bcg729.
Link instruction : http://saravnandm.blogspot.com/2016/07/pjsip-25-g729-codec.html
But `checking bcg729 disable.... yes`  -> wrong

So someone can help me the tutorial to build PJSIP support bcg729 for Andoird. Thanks you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I have get repo on github, use docker, to build everything from begin to start PJSIP with openssl, opus, g729.. It working good.
`https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android-builder`